# Heroku deploy error code=H10 rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gemfile

im trying to deploy a Rails app on Heroku, but when i use "heroku open" it's says Application Error; when i put Heroku logs it shows me this

```
    2015-10-15T18:30:09.728340+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
2015-10-15T18:30:09.728341+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2015-10-15T18:30:09.728342+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2015-10-15T18:30:10.378446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-10-15T18:30:10.402146+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-15T18:30:10.403542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-15T18:30:13.028434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 12177 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2015-10-15T18:30:15.549440+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `instance_eval': ./config/unicorn.rb:1: unknown regexp options - cfg (SyntaxError)
2015-10-15T18:30:15.549450+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `reload'
2015-10-15T18:30:15.549451+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T18:30:15.549452+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `new'
2015-10-15T18:30:15.549455+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
2015-10-15T18:30:15.549454+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T18:30:15.549456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2015-10-15T18:30:15.549458+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2015-10-15T18:30:15.549460+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2015-10-15T18:30:16.210700+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-10-15T18:30:16.226674+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-15T18:32:22.548711+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT resource by juampi_fs@hotmail.com
2015-10-15T18:32:22.548770+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by juampi_fs@hotmail.com
2015-10-15T18:32:25.890823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 6751 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2015-10-15T18:32:27.867856+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `instance_eval': ./config/unicorn.rb:1: unknown regexp options - cfg (SyntaxError)
2015-10-15T18:32:27.867868+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `reload'
2015-10-15T18:32:27.867869+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T18:32:27.867871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T18:32:27.867870+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `new'
2015-10-15T18:32:27.867872+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
2015-10-15T18:32:27.867873+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2015-10-15T18:32:27.867873+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2015-10-15T18:32:27.867874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2015-10-15T18:32:28.584818+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-10-15T18:32:28.598560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-15T18:32:22.697451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-15T18:37:07.605744+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-10-15T18:37:07.605753+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-10-15T18:37:07.646360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-15T18:37:07.516556+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e621bdf by juampi_fs@hotmail.com
2015-10-15T18:37:07.516556+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by juampi_fs@hotmail.com
2015-10-15T18:37:11.450834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 52032 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2015-10-15T18:37:13.685427+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `instance_eval': ./config/unicorn.rb:1: unknown regexp options - cfg (SyntaxError)
2015-10-15T18:37:13.685452+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `reload'
2015-10-15T18:37:13.685454+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T18:37:13.685456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `new'
2015-10-15T18:37:13.685456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T18:37:13.685457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
2015-10-15T18:37:13.685459+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2015-10-15T18:37:13.685460+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2015-10-15T18:37:13.685461+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2015-10-15T18:37:14.448547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-10-15T18:37:14.464038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-15T18:39:22.600512+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by juampi_fs@hotmail.com
2015-10-15T18:39:29.514874+00:00 heroku[run.1972]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-10-15T18:39:29.468552+00:00 heroku[run.1972]: Awaiting client
2015-10-15T18:39:29.766286+00:00 heroku[run.1972]: State changed from starting to up
2015-10-15T18:39:37.893193+00:00 heroku[run.1972]: Process exited with status 0
2015-10-15T18:39:37.907124+00:00 heroku[run.1972]: State changed from up to complete
2015-10-15T18:39:43.915728+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iaw2015.herokuapp.com request_id=b2d8f5bb-d43d-4329-a05b-ae18f4a7011d fwd="181.166.75.96" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-15T18:43:56.477226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iaw2015.herokuapp.com request_id=bc7ca591-1d9f-4353-958d-739046bac574 fwd="181.166.75.96" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-15T19:00:11.810029+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by juampi_fs@hotmail.com
2015-10-15T19:00:11.810029+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1326623 by juampi_fs@hotmail.com
2015-10-15T19:00:11.899758+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-10-15T19:00:11.899768+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-10-15T19:00:11.926792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-15T19:00:16.217241+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 5694 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2015-10-15T19:00:19.599403+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `instance_eval': ./config/unicorn.rb:1: unknown regexp options - cfg (SyntaxError)
2015-10-15T19:00:19.599415+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `reload'
2015-10-15T19:00:19.599416+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T19:00:19.599417+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `new'
2015-10-15T19:00:19.599422+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2015-10-15T19:00:19.599417+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T19:00:19.599421+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2015-10-15T19:00:19.599420+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
2015-10-15T19:00:19.599421+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2015-10-15T19:00:20.715192+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-10-15T19:00:24.892661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 11658 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2015-10-15T19:00:27.130550+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `instance_eval': ./config/unicorn.rb:1: unknown regexp options - cfg (SyntaxError)
2015-10-15T19:00:27.130561+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T19:00:27.130559+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `reload'
2015-10-15T19:00:27.130562+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `new'
2015-10-15T19:00:27.130562+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `initialize'
2015-10-15T19:00:27.130563+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
2015-10-15T19:00:27.130564+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2015-10-15T19:00:27.130564+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2015-10-15T19:00:27.130565+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2015-10-15T19:00:27.698542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-10-15T19:00:27.709053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-15T19:00:20.729656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-15T19:00:20.730879+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-15T19:02:28.161661+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `db:migrate` by juampi_fs@hotmail.com
2015-10-15T19:02:33.937454+00:00 heroku[run.3725]: Awaiting client
2015-10-15T19:02:33.996726+00:00 heroku[run.3725]: Starting process with command `db:migrate`
2015-10-15T19:02:34.210232+00:00 heroku[run.3725]: State changed from starting to up
2015-10-15T19:02:37.035686+00:00 heroku[run.3725]: Process exited with status 127
2015-10-15T19:02:37.054522+00:00 heroku[run.3725]: State changed from up to complete
2015-10-15T19:04:33.739447+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by juampi_fs@hotmail.com
2015-10-15T19:04:41.217444+00:00 heroku[run.8562]: Awaiting client
2015-10-15T19:04:41.248636+00:00 heroku[run.8562]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-10-15T19:04:41.516412+00:00 heroku[run.8562]: State changed from starting to up
2015-10-15T19:04:47.431803+00:00 heroku[run.8562]: Process exited with status 0
2015-10-15T19:04:47.440395+00:00 heroku[run.8562]: State changed from up to complete
2015-10-15T19:05:10.826950+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iaw2015.herokuapp.com request_id=9fbfd91a-cf1d-45d9-a09c-a255cb9e0727 fwd="181.166.75.96" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I can't find the issue, i take a windows rails project and deployed on  Capitan OS X

Comment: Please post your /config/unicorn.rb file. That's where the errors begin according to your log.

Comment: i fix it changes unicorn file for another gem

Comment: It looks like you had an error in your Unicorn config: `./config/unicorn.rb:1: unknown regexp options - cfg (SyntaxError)`